# JAXBElement<Byte> declaration

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've generated classes from my XML .xsd and am trying to set a field `EndpointID` within in the class `MeterSessionInputRF`. The problem I'm having is that the `setEndpointID` method only accepts `JAXBElement<Byte>` as it's parameter.

I'm currently query a database to get the input for the `setEndpointID` method. This input can be a string, char, whatever I want it to be.

How do I create a `JAXBElement<Byte>`? I've tried using the ObjectFactory class but when I try and use it, I don't have the option of creating such an object.

Here's the code I already have to give some perspective.

```
if(moduleResults.next()){
    MeterSessionInputRF msiRF = new MeterSessionInputRF();
    msiRF.setRFFrequency(moduleResults.getFloat("id_amr_module"));
    JAXBElement<Byte> endpointType;
    byte epT = moduleResults.getByte("cd_module_typ");
    endpointType.setValue(epT);
    msiRF.setEndpointType(endpointType);
}
```

I keep getting the error that endpointType may have not been initialized. Is there a correct way to create the `JAXBElement<Byte>`?

Comment: Ahhh thank you. It was under createMeterSessionInputRFEndpointType. So hard to find!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ObjectFactory` class generated by XJC should have a method to do that for you. I know you said it wasn't there, but check again, there should be some method that returns an object of that type.